# Turning off encryption with OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

I want to run a local OpenVPN for localhost access (loopback), so local encryption is a complete waste of time. So how do I turn off the whole thing? I'm using OpenVPN 2.4.7.

Comment: Then why bother with the VPN in the first place?

Comment: Sandboxes don't usually have a good way to expose a sandbox instance to the internet on its own IP(v6) address with full IP(v6) capabilities. Instead I just get an outbound TCP connection. OpenVPN would allow sandboxes to have public IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following options in your config should do the trick:

```
cipher none
auth none
```

Note: I haven't tried it though.